# I'm using Python and Telethon as a Telegram client to get new messages, but need to identify a reply and which message it replying to

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have a working Python script with Telethon and it logs in with my account, connects to the correct channel and gets new messages just fine. It also can identify if it is a new message vs a reply to a previous message. I just need to figure out which message the reply is replying to. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import requests
import configparser
import threading
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.tl.types import (
    PeerChannel
)

from os import system
system("title " + "My Telegram Client")

# Reading Configs
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# Setting configuration values
api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']

api_hash = str(api_hash)

phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']

subjectFilter = ['']
levelFilter = ['']

client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

async def main(phone):
    await client.start()
    print("TELEGRAM CLIENT CREATED")
    # Ensure you're authorized
    if await client.is_user_authorized() == False:
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        try:
            await client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            await client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))

me = await client.get_me()
user_input_channel=PeerChannel(int(-1172633073)) #BL TECH PRO
print("Connected to BL Tech Pro Telegram Channel")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
    async def newMessageListener(event):
    newMessage = event.message.message
    
    #CHECK IF MESSAGE IS A REPLY
    if event.message.is_reply:
        print("reply")
    else:
        print("not reply")    
    
    #PRINT MESSAGE TO SCREEN
    print(newMessage)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, I figured it out.
This prints out the original message with all the message properties:

```
if event.message.is_reply:
    orgMessage = await event.get_reply_message()
    print("reply")
    print(orgMessage)
else:
    print("not reply")
```